# Mapping a Logarithmic Conical Spiral onto a 2D Plane

Tags: geometry

I have designed a conical logarithmic spiral antenna.  I now need to fabricate the metal for the spiral by laser cutting it from flat sheet metal, which should be possible since a cone is a developable surface.  I just need to know how to map the 3D spiral to a flat surface!
[Conical Log Spiral Antenna](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Mkkr.png)
[Angles and Distances](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9a8B5.jpg)

Given the equations for the inner and outer edges of the spiral  ($\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$, respectively) in terms of the angle $\phi$ around the apex and the distances along the cone measured from the apex:
$\rho_1 = e^{b\phi}$
$\rho_2 = e^{b(\phi-\delta)} = K\rho_1$
and $\theta_0$ is the half-angle at the apex.  How do I generate the flattened spiral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The cone with half-angle $\theta_0$ has the length of its base $s=2\pi r=2\pi L\sin\theta_0$. So when you rotate the point around the symmetry axis by angle $\phi$, its image on a net rotates by $\varphi = \phi\sin\theta_0$.

Thus, the equations of your edges can be easily given in polar coordinates:
$$
\rho_1(\varphi)=\exp\frac{b\varphi}{\sin\theta_0},\\
\rho_2(\varphi)=K\rho_1(\varphi)
$$